# Join attributes from point layer to overlapping polygon layer in a one-to-one relationship in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, spatial-join, expression

I have a polygon layer and a point layer. I want to get the attributes from the point layer and join them to the polygon layer in a one-to-one relationship. This is normally easily done with the Join attributes by location tool but it doesn't work here as the polygons are overlapping.

What i have is polygons that are an exact copy of them selves but their attributes are different. i want to take one of the points that falls within the polygon and merge it attributes into one of the polygons.

[image: Example of my polygons and points]

It doesn't show it in the picture but there are 3 polygons stacked on top of each other. It doesn't matter what point goes to what polygon it just needs to be one point to one polygon.

EDIT: I was advised I did not provide enough detail on my overall goal. What I am trying to do is match my team's water meter layer up with another team's list of water meters. The issue is we do not have any form of ID to link it to their system (they have the master list of water meters). So what I was doing is using the Join by location tool with the water meters to get the parcel ID they sit in, and then use that parcel ID to do a merge in Excel against the other team's parcel ID. This worked for all parcels with 1 water meter per parcel but parcels with more then 1 water meter per parcel didn't work when using Join attributes by location.

EDIT: With Babel's help this is my code attempt. wserviceconnection is my point layer and Facility_I is the attribute I want to bring from the point layer to the polygon layer. When running this code it returns 'Facility_I' in the attribute field which is not what I expected as Facility_I contains numeric ID's e.g. 1234, 4321, 5678 etc

```
     overlay_intersects( 'wserviceconnection_1222df7a_de54_4063_ab09_4d911e6af8a3',  'Facility_I', limit:=10)
 [ array_find( 
     aggregate( 
        @layer,
        'array_agg',
        $id,
        filter:=intersects ($geometry, geometry(@parent))
        ),
        $id
)]
```

[image]

Comment: Are the polygons all 100% overlapping, and the points not overlapping? Also, is there always 1-1 points/polygons? Just trying to make sure what you have above is the entire question.

Comment: Not sure what your workflow or task is and how what you intend really makes sense... Of course it's possible to do what you ask for, but depending on your final task, there might be better alternatives. Thus to me, it seems kind of an XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @TomBrennan There is around 60k polygons so i can't check them all but i do believe they are 100% overlapping and the points are not overlapping. There is always 1 point per polygon.

Comment: Field names should be in double quotes eg "Facility_I", not 'Facility_I'

Comment: Indeed, as @TomBrennan mentioned, you put `'Facility_I'` in single quotes, I don't know why. Like this, the expression returns the string `Facility_I`. If you want to get the value of the field, enclose it in double quotes or without any quotes at all: as you can see in my expression, I have `name` without quotes, so no idea why you put quotes. Also, I'm not sure if it is indeed `Facility_I` and not rather `Facility_ID` as we can see on your screenshot. Also make sure your points are indeed within the polygon. If it doesn't work, provide sample data.

Comment: @Babel Sorry for the errors I have not long started my GIS studies so i'm still new. I selected Facility_I from the list of attributes in the expression builder and QGIS put the single quotes around Facility_I.

Comment: So does it work now?

Comment: @Babel Running now as we speak. It has been running for over an hour but hasn't crashed yet. Will accept answer when it finishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your point layer contains a field called `name` you want to join 1:1 to the same number of identical, overlapping polygons (duplicate geometries).

Use this expression on the polygon layer:

```
overlay_intersects ('point', name, limit:=10)  -- adapt the limit to the max. no of points that are within one polygon
[array_find (
    aggregate (
        @layer, 
        'array_agg',
        $id,
        filter:=intersects ($geometry, geometry(@parent))
    ),
    $id
)]
```

*Screenshot: left, smaller polygon exists in 2 identical copies, larger right polygon in 3 identical copies:*
[image]

Comment: This didn't work for me. See original post for results.

Comment: Seems you made it work now regarding the fact you accepted the answer?